# Scaling a matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, scaling

I have to process a matrix and then scale it as a gray scale image. In matlab I could achieve this using mat2gray function. How can I do the same in opencv?

```
for(int i=0;i<c4.rows-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<c4.cols-1;j++)
    {

        value=100*sin(2*pi*j*18.0/imgCols);
        c5.at<Vec2d>(i,j)=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the input format of your mat? `c5.at<Vec2d>` means you have 2 channels with double values (if you mean c5). What do you mean by `scale it as gray scale image`? Gray scale image is only one channel. If you have float or double values in that one channel, you should scale them to be values between 0 and 1 to display as black (0) to white (1). If you instead want to convert a color image to a grayscale image, what is your input format?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell that i'm just getting started with openCV. My input matrix is a single channel image and usage of  c5.at<Vec2d>(i,j)=value; might be incorrect.

Comment: Answer to the question what does "scale it as gray scale image?" mean. for(int i=0;i<c4.rows-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<c4.cols-1;j++)
    {   c5(i,j)=poly(x);}}//polynomial returns values in the range -100 to 100. Now i want to convert this matrix c5 to a gray scale image in the ranges 0-255

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

cv::Mat greyMat, colorMat;
cv::cvtColor(colorMat, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: this only works if the image is in BGR format. As he accesses with `at<Vec2d>` I'm not sure what he even means by `scale it as a gray scale image`

Comment: @Micka value is a double or float, so the image has 3 chars there (so 3 channels). I think he was not understanding the `at` method.

Comment: Try my answer below and use it like: cv::Mat scaled = mat2gray(yourMat); scaled = 255*scaled; cv::Mat converted; scaled.convertTo(converted, Cv_8UC1);

Answer (score 0):

If you have already single channel matrices and want to scale their values between 0 and 1 (for displaying), try this one:

```
cv::Mat mat2gray(cv::Mat inMat)
{
    //idea: to be scaled between 0 and 1, compute for each value: val := (val - minVal)/(maxVal-minVal)

    if(inMat.channels() != 1) std::cout << "mat2gray only works for single channel floating point matrices" << std::endl;

    // here we assume floating point matrices (single/double precision both ok)
    double minVal, maxVal;

    cv::minMaxLoc(inMat, &minVal, &maxVal);

    cv::Mat scaledMat = inMat.clone();
    scaledMat = scaledMat - cv::Mat(inMat.size(), inMat.type(), cv::Scalar(minVal));
    scaledMat = ((1.0)/(maxVal-minVal))*scaledMat;

    return scaledMat;
}
```