# Pixel values differ between opencv and matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, pixel

When I am displaying the pixel values of an image (a RGB image converted to grayscale) using "display" function in matlab, I found that the pixel values are less than 1 (all values are between 0 and 1). Whereas when I do the same in opencv, I am getting higher values. Why the change in values happen ? 
Open CV code and matlab code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < img1.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img1.cols; j++)
    {
        cout << (unsigned int)img1.at<uchar>(i, j) << endl;
    }
}

Matlab code:

gI=rgb2gray(I);
imshow(gI);
```

Comment: What is the image's datatype? `double`, `uint8`, some special image class? How do *you* convert between MATLAB and OpenCV? My guess is that in MATLAB you are dealing with normalized `double` values (0-1) whereas in OpenCV they are `uint8` (0-255) or something similar. If this is indeed the case, you can find the maximum value of the datatype and convert between the two systems.

Comment: did matlab use mat2gray function? try my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483013/scaling-a-matrix-in-opencv

Comment: maybe post your sample code in matlab and opencv

Comment: My Mat is of type 8UC3. How to convert normalised double value of MATLAB to 8UC3 ? Multipying by 255 alone is enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you.
No one guarantees that the conversion of RGB to gray-scale will yield the same result. There are 2 reasons

1. The conversion is not a mathematical correct formula but rather subjective issue. Over the course of the last 50 years a few different standards (mainly for color television supporting greyscale signals) were written of how to convert RGB to gray level. Different standards lead to almost identical visible results, though the actual values of the pixels differ a bit (~roughly 0.2%). You can read more about the standards in Wikipedia. For example: One standard defines the conversion of RGB to gray while another defines conversion of RGB to YUV and taking Y channel as the gray scale. There are few other standards as well (preserving luminosity, intensity, contrast, etc). Since the preference of the standards change over time, it is hard to know how exactly the RGB to gray is implemented. [Here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) is an example of 3 different methods. Open CV uses completely different method (`0.299f*RED +  0.587f*GREEN + 0.114f*BLUE` [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)) while Matlab uses another method (0.2989*RED + 0.587*GREEN + 0.1140*BLUE. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)). Note the difference between openCV 0.299 and Matlabs 0.2989.
   More information can be found in this answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity))
2. Second reason - different floating point representation across hardware and software. Floating point computation (regardless whether it is double or float) is not precise and depends on the specific hardware you use, type of compiler with witch you build a software and specific compiler directives. Same mathematical calculation can yield slightly different results on different computers or even on the same computer in 2 different programs. So unfortunately you will not get exactly the same results for RGB to gray conversion but if you round the values to range of [0..255] you will typically get a discrepancy of no more than 2 levels. I would say that in 99.9% pixels you will get the same value and in the others difference of 1. 2 is very rare and I have never seen a difference of 3, unless you do few sequential conversions like RGB->XYZ->HSV->YUV

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was really informative. One more doubt. How to convert normalised double value of MATLAB to 8UC3 ? Multipying by 255 alone is enough ?

Comment: There is no exact answer here. You can multiply by 255 and round it. This produces a very slight mistake. Another approach is multiply by 256, take floor (instead of round) and correct every 256 to 255. This is a slower algorithm but gives more accurate results. You might want to stretch the contrast to 1 before converting to integer values. In that case, calculate the minimum value among all the pixels in the image and subtract it from the entire image. Then calculate the maximum and divide by it. Thus you force the range to be [0..1]. Now you can apply one of the techniques above

Comment: Typically, contrast stretching, multiplying by 255 and taking round() considered the default approach.  If you are sure that the double values are correctly normalized [0..1], you can skip the contrast stretching step.

Answer (score 1):

> My Mat is of type 8UC3. How to convert normalised double value of
>   MATLAB to 8UC3 ? Multipying by 255 alone is enough?

In the case of `8UC3` bytes then **yes** its enough to just multiply by 255. They are designed to work that way. The **3** in 8UC**3** means the three channels **Red**, **Green** and **Blue**

Anyway, converting between `0 to 255` range values and `0.0 to 1.0` range values

```
//Psuedo-code formula:

col_val = 210; //range 0-255
normalised = col_val / 255; //always divide by 255 for a normalised to "1.0" version

normal_reverse_to255 = normalised * 255; //make it back into "0 to 255" range
```

expected result : 
 
**col_val** = 210 `//original value before normalised` 
**normalised** = 0.8235 `//...294117647058 etc etc //after normalised to 0.0 to 1.0 range` 
**normal_reverse_to255** = 210; `//multiply result is same as original value`

Hope that's helpful to you.

**Edit:** 
I just realised you are using `gI=rgb2gray(I);` to get your grayscale image.

try something like: 
`cvtColor(src,dst,CV_GRAY2RGB);` as hijacked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606302/opencv-how-to-convert-cv-8uc1-mat-to-cv-8uc3/14610924#14610924)