# implement mat2gray in Opencv with Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I have the same problem with him: [Scaling a matrix in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483013/scaling-a-matrix-in-opencv)

I got the same problem with him, I have a colored picture, I used matlab to read the picture: `Input = imread('input1.jpg');`, and the format of the picture is 612x612x3 uint8,  I print the 5x5x1 pixel in the picture as below:`Input(1:5,1:5,1)`

```
 201   201   201   201   201
 201   201   201   201   201
 202   202   202   202   202
 203   203   203   203   203
 204   204   204   204   204
```

by using the mat2gray function: `rgb_out = mat2gray(Input);`, these pixels can be transformed to this, they all in the range between 0 and 1: `rgb_out(1:5,1:5,1)`

```
0.9684    0.9455    0.9266    0.9099    0.9047
0.9657    0.9542    0.9432    0.9354    0.9299
0.9642    0.9571    0.9502    0.9495    0.9456
0.9621    0.9609    0.9562    0.9532    0.9516
0.9673    0.9633    0.9597    0.9580    0.9575
```

so the question is how can I implement this in Opencv with Python, I tried the code as below:

```
print(Input)
rgb_out = np.zeros(Input.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.normalize(Input,rgb_out,1,0,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
print(rgb_out)
```

but the first print is :

```
[[[205 207 201]
  [205 207 201]
  [205 207 201]
  ..., 
  [232 254 242]
  [232 254 242]
  [231 253 241]]...
```

and the elements in the rgb_out is no more than 1 or 0. please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input matrix is an integer datatype and your output  matrix is defined to be `np.uint8` (an integer type). By default, `cv2.normalize` is going to return a result that is the same datatype as the inputs. You'll want to use floating point datatypes if you want output values between `0.0` and `1.0`.

One option would be to convert your input and outputs to `np.double` prior to calling `cv2.normalize`

```
A = np.double(A)
out = np.zeros(A.shape, np.double)
normalized = cv2.normalize(A, out, 1.0, 0.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Alternately, you can specify a floating point datatype to `cv2.normalize` via the `dtype` kwarg to force a specific output datatype.

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
out = np.zeros(A.shape, np.double)
normalized = cv2.normalize(A, out, 1.0, 0.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_64F)
```

Comment: That's not correct. You need to divide by 255, not normalize. The fact that normalization works in this case is just luck, since the original image has both 0 and 255 values.

Comment: @Miki He wants to simulate `mat2gray`'s behavior in MATLAB. `mat2gray` does not divide by 255, but rather scales all values in the input so that they span 0 to 1 regardless of the maximum value of the input.

Comment: I want to scale the image not from 0 to 1 but from 0 to 255

Comment: @semicolon you just need to change the 1.0 to 255.0 or pass an input that is an 8-bit unsigned integer

Answer (score 0):

Referenced from [@Suever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808617/3814219) answer, here my working one with the identical variable to Matlab's mat2gray.

```
# python function replica of matlab's mat2gray
def matlab_mat2grey(A = false, alpha = min(A.flatten()), beta = max(A.flatten())):
  I = A
  cv2.normalize(A, I, alpha , beta ,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
  I = np.uint8(I)
  return I
```